# How to pass listview item to another fragment and open an url

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, android-fragments, webview

I want to get string from listview from fragmen1 and sent it to fragment 2 and open a url. But I cannt get it to work. please help.

**Im trying to get string from fragment1**

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_url_list, container, false);

        final String[] urlarray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.default_urls); //got array list from string.xml good
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,urlarray);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

//here im trying to get string when clicked and send it to another fragment
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){ 
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)  {

                Bundle args = new Bundle ();
                args.putString("url","value"); //what should i put in value if im trying to pass string from array
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.web_fragment,fragment, fragment.getTag()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

**Second fragment:**

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web, container, false);

        
        WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);

        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        String url= bundle.getString("url");  //trying to get string from fragment1 and open url
        webView.loadUrl(url);


       /* webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }
        });*/
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);



        return view;
    }
```

When I Run the program I can see both fragments in the screen. List on the left and (if I webload("any url") I can see the url. So it is working fine until then. But I need it to change when another url from the list is clicked. That is why im using onclicklistener and trying to pass the url as a string to fragment 2. So here I Would webload the string and open it.

Answer (score 0):

according to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener#onItemClick(android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long)), you can call
`getItemAtPosition(position)` from within `onItemClick()` to get the data (in this case, the string) associated with the item that was clicked,.

Comment: it is not working

Comment: It's hard to know how to help without more information.
What does `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)` return?

Comment: what else do u need?

Comment: When you call `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)` inside your `onItemClick()` function, what does it return?

Comment: I actually do not know. Do I have to use parent? that is automatically placed by the software

Comment: `parent` is the ListView.  It has the list of all the urls.  
Invoking `parent.getItemAtPosition(5)` is like saying to the ListView, "give me the 5th url in the list".
`position` is the number of the item in the list that was clicked on.  So `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)` gives you the url the user clicked on.